# Does the lexical hypothesis have any role in 'creativity'?

Tags: personality, creativity

The [lexical hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_hypothesis) was used to I think *create* the 5 factor model of personality.

Has anything similar been done in the science of 'creativity'?

While, clearly, "creativity" is a component of intelligence, even if it is also one in personality.

---

What got me thinking about this, is the measurement of 'creativity', which is I think notoriously difficult, even more so that aptitude in general. Specifically, I was thinking about how it seems that 'fluency' seems lexically close to some terms close to creativity.

How would *general* cognitive fluency, as it is measured by cognitive test, correlate with creativity?

---

fluency, noun

- the ability to express oneself easily and articulately.

fantasy, noun

- a fanciful mental image, typically one on which a person often dwells and which reflects their conscious or unconscious wishes

imagination, noun

- the faculty or action of forming new ideas, or images or concepts of 
  external objects not present to the senses.

etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Jauk et al. (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.intell.2013.03.003) talks about the relationship between intelligence and creativity whilst [King, et al. (1996)](https://doi.org/10.1006/jrpe.1996.0013) talks about the the relationship between the 5-factor model and creativity.

> **4.2. Personality predictors of creative potential**
>
> When performing separate multiple regression analyses in samples of lower and higher intelligence, we found that openness to experiences predicts creative potential in the subsample above the threshold whereas conscientiousness is negatively related to creative potential in the lower IQ range.
>
> While it is well documented that that there exists a positive association between openness and creative potential ([Batey & Furnham, 2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18341234); Feist, 2010; [King et al., 1996](https://doi.org/10.1006/jrpe.1996.0013)), the present result points to an interaction between intelligence and openness: High creative potential is not possible with a low level IQ; but once the intelligence threshold is met, openness may explain to some extent whether the required cognitive disposition is actually turned into high creative potential ([Jauk, et al. 2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.intell.2013.03.003))

**References**

Batey M., Furnham A. (2006). Creativity, intelligence, and personality: A critical review of the scattered literature. *Genetic, Social, and General Psychology Monographs*. 132(4) 355–429.
PMID: [18341234](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18341234)

Feist G.J. (2010). The function of personality in creativity: The nature and nurture of the creative personality. In: Kaufman J.C., Sternberg R.J., editors. *The Cambridge handbook of creativity*. New York: Cambridge University Press;  pp. 113–130.

Jauk, E., Benedek, M., Dunst, B., & Neubauer, A. C. (2013). The relationship between intelligence and creativity: New support for the threshold hypothesis by means of empirical breakpoint detection. *Intelligence*, 41(4), 212–221.
DOI: [10.1016/j.intell.2013.03.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.intell.2013.03.003)

King L. A., Walker L. M. & Broyles S. J. (1996). Creativity and the five-factor model. *Journal of Research in Personality*. 30(2), 189–203.
DOI: [10.1006/jrpe.1996.0013](https://doi.org/10.1006/jrpe.1996.0013)